# How to get all RegEx capture groups as a single string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently on https://regex101.com/ and have the following inputted (with global flag):

```
REGULAR EXPRESSION: ([A-Z])
TEST STRING: ABCdefGHI
```

On the right in `Match Information` the following string is in Group 1: `ABCGHI`

I'm trying to replicate this in JavaScript and I'm having trouble:

```
var myString = "ABCdefGHI";
var myRegexp = /([A-Z])/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]);
```

The above just returns `A`. Desired result: `ABCGHI`

I've looked around a bit and there seems to be a way to do it by looping through the resulting RegEx grouping array, pushing all elements, and then doing a string join. I'm wondering if that is completely necessary or if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: On regex101, you can "save regex" and it generates a link to your regex and test string which you can share.  Since I'm not getting the same results as you, it might be useful for you to add that link to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array.join('')` where `array` is return value of `string.match(re)`:

```js
var myString = "ABCdefGHI";
var myRegexp = /([A-Z])/g;

var result = myString.match(myRegexp).join('');

console.log(result);
//=>"ABCGHI"
```

Or else if you're allowed to change regex then use negation:

```
var repl = myString.replace(/[^A-Z]+/, '')
//=> "ABCGHI"
```

Comment: Okay, this is clean enough I suppose. I was wondering if there was a way to get the result in a single grouping, but if not I'll make do with this.

Comment: See updated answer, may be you're looking for `string.replace`

Comment: Actually, the negation may be just what I'm looking for. Thanks for the idea that may be the ticket!